# How to link a checkbox(:checked) to a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, filtering

I have setup a filter list which checkboxes. When the specific checkbox is checked, i need to interact with a class so it hides through JavaScript. Also, if multiple checkboxes are checked, i need to show these items with both the classes. I have this:

HTML:

```
   <div class="categs" id="filters">

                <div class="categhead">
                    <p>Ranking</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categsort">
                    <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagchallenger" value="challenger" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="tagchallenger">Challenger</label>
                </div>

                <div class="categsort">
                    <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagmaster" value="master" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="tagmaster">Master | Diamond</label>
                </div>
                <div class="categsort">
                    <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagplat" value="plat" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="tagplat">Platinum | Gold</label>
                </div>

                <div class="categsort">
                    <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagsilver" value="silver" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="tagsilver">Silver | Bronze</label>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.hide-checkbox'), function(element) {
                    element.style.display = 'none';
                });
                </script>

            </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
     var streameach = $('.streampic .row .col-md-4');

     function updateContentVisibility(){
     var checked = $('#filters :checkbox:checked');
     if(checked.length){
     streameach.hide();
     checked.each(function() {

        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
     });

     } else {
     streameach.show();
     }
     }

     $('#filters :checkbox').click(updateContentVisibility);
     updateContentVisibility();
     }
```

And then i also have

```
     <div class="streamtag1">...</div>
```

And

```
    var stream0 = "<? echo $lolarray->streams[0]->channel->name; ?>";
    if (stream0 == "riotgames") {

    $('streamtag1').addClass('master');

    };
```

Now when the checkbox 'master' is clicked, it hides all the divs, but doesn't show the ones that have the added master class,which should be connected to that checkbox.

Comment: streameach is undefined, please post working code

Comment: `console.log(checked);` - see if your code is catching the right checkboxes.

Comment: It works fine in this stripped-down version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/zkn7vw6e/. So, the problem must be elsewhere. It really would help for you to post the full code, or better yet, a jsFiddle.

Comment: "witch checkboxes", haha <cackle>...

Comment: I think you'll have to setup a non-working example with the multiple checkboxes to show us how this is supposed to work ?

Comment: Edited post completely, added all code. It's not working like this, it might be caused by the .addClass ?

Comment: It might but, having read the updated question, I can't work out what should happen. Checking one checkbox should hide the elements with the class-name of the `<input>` element's value? If multiple checkboxes are checked should all elements of those value-classes be hidden? Shown?

Comment: Wait.. look, from default, none checked, all elements with all classes should show, when one checkbox is checked, that value (with it's class) should show, the other classes should hide. I'm new to coding these big projects and can't track of my own code anymore...

Comment: So all non-checked checkboxes should have their associated sections hidden?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, checked should be shown, non-checked hidden.

Comment: To add to that, currently when selecting a checkbox that has a class, EVERYTHING shows, when clicking a checkbox that doesn't have a class yet, all hides.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up like the below:

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1knr09c/2/)

```js
     function updateContentVisibility() {
         $('.hide-checkbox').each(function () {
             if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 $('.' + $(this).val()).hide();
             } else $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
         });
     }

     $('.hide-checkbox').change(function () {
         updateContentVisibility();
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="categsort">
<input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagriot" value="riot">
<label for="tagriot">RIOT</label>
<input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagblue" value="blue">
<label for="tagblue">blue</label>
<input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="taggreen" value="green">
<label for="taggreen">green</label>
<input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagred" value="red">
<label for="tagred">red</label>
</div>
<div class="riot">riot</div>
<br>
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<br>
<div class="green">green</div>
<br>
<div class="red">red</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the question description, and some clarification in the comments to that question, I'd suggest the following approach, using jQuery:

```
// selecting the <input> elements of class-name 'hide-checkbox',
// binding an anonymous function to handle the 'change' event:
$('input.hide-checkbox').on('change', function () {

  // selecting all elements whose class-name is equal to the
  // <input> element's value, and using the toggle(switch)
  // approach, to show if the switch is true (the checkbox is checked)
  // and hide if the switch is false (the checkbox is unchecked):
  $('.' + this.value).toggle(this.checked);

// triggering the change event, so that the function runs on page-load,
// to hide/show as appropriate:
}).change();
```

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.hide-checkbox'), function(element) {
  element.style.display = 'none';
});

$('input.hide-checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $('.' + this.value).toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input:checked + label {
  color: #f90;
}
#contents div[class] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  width: 80%;
}
#contents div[class]::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categs" id="filters">
  <div class="categhead">
    <p>Ranking</p>
  </div>
  <div class="categsort">
    <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagchallenger" value="challenger" style="display: none;" />
    <label for="tagchallenger">Challenger</label>
  </div>
  <div class="categsort">
    <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagmaster" value="master" style="display: none;" />
    <label for="tagmaster">Master | Diamond</label>
  </div>
  <div class="categsort">
    <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagplat" value="plat" style="display: none;" />
    <label for="tagplat">Platinum | Gold</label>
  </div>
  <div class="categsort">
    <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagsilver" value="silver" style="display: none;" />
    <label for="tagsilver">Silver | Bronze</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="contents">
  <div class="challenger"></div>
  <div class="master"></div>
  <div class="plat"></div>
  <div class="silver"></div>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c7qgb5tr/3/), for experiementation.

Or, with plain JavaScript:

```
// creating a named function to handle the show/hide functionality:
function toggleView() {

    // a cached reference to the changed <input>:
    var control = this,

    // a reference to whether the <input> is checked or not:
        check = control.checked,

    // retrieving all elements with a class-name equal to the
    // <input> element's value:
        targets = document.querySelectorAll('.' + control.value);

    // using Array.prototype.forEach(), with Function.prototype.call(),
    // to iterate over the found elements:
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(targets, function (node) {

        // setting the display property of each found-element's
        // style property; if the checkbox is checked we set
        // the display to 'block', if not we set it to 'none':
        node.style.display = check ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
}

// creating a 'change' event so that we can trigger the function
// to run on page-load:
var changeEvent = new Event('change');

// As above, iterating over the '.hide-checkbox' elements:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.hide-checkbox'), function (element) {

    // hiding the elements:
    element.style.display = 'none';

    // binding the named function (toggleView)
    // to handle the change event:
    element.addEventListener('change', toggleView);

    // triggering the change event on each of the
    // '.hide-checkbox' elements:
    element.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
});
```

```js
function toggleView() {
    var control = this,
        check = control.checked,
        targets = document.querySelectorAll('.' + control.value);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(targets, function (node) {
        node.style.display = check ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
}

var changeEvent = new Event('change');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.hide-checkbox'), function (element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
    element.addEventListener('change', toggleView);
    element.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
});
```

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input:checked + label {
    color: #f90;
}
#contents div[class] {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#contents div[class]::before {
    content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="categs" id="filters">
    <div class="categhead">
        <p>Ranking</p>
    </div>
    <div class="categsort">
        <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagchallenger" value="challenger" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="tagchallenger">Challenger</label>
    </div>
    <div class="categsort">
        <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagmaster" value="master" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="tagmaster">Master | Diamond</label>
    </div>
    <div class="categsort">
        <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagplat" value="plat" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="tagplat">Platinum | Gold</label>
    </div>
    <div class="categsort">
        <input class="hide-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tagsilver" value="silver" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="tagsilver">Silver | Bronze</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contents">
    <div class="challenger"></div>
    <div class="master"></div>
    <div class="plat"></div>
    <div class="silver"></div>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demmo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c7qgb5tr/2/) for experiementation/development.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Event()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Event.target.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Man.. dunno what i'm doing wrong here. I copied the first bit of javascript using jquery and pasted that under, even used your css... When clicked it STILL shows all classes, instead of only the one clicked...

Comment: Do the linked demos work okay? Is the jQuery, or the plain JavaScript function, being called properly (pop a `console.log("function's called!")` into the anonymous function (jQuery) and the `toggleView()` function (plain JavaScript) as a simple diagnostic. Have you wrapped the code in a `$(document).ready(function(){ /* code in here */ });` (or appropriate alternative), or is your JavaScript/jQuery in a `<script>` block before the closing `</body>` tag, so the DOM exists before the JavaScript runs?

Comment: Just regarding my code, lets say i haven't made a class for the value challenger, but i have for master. When i check the challenger checkbox it hides all. When i check the master checkbox it hides all, then shows all again. How?

Comment: All JS code is wrapped in a <script> tag just after my checkboxes (before the footer). And yes, the demos work fine..

Comment: You want it to do that, or that's a problem you're having with my answer? If it's what you want then update your question, show a representative sample of the HTML that you're trying to show and hide, and clearly update the question text to better explain what you want (as you did in that comment, though I'm not sure if it was a request or criticism). I'd suggest, if you're using jQuery, that you try wrapping in `$(document).ready();` just to see if it works. Otherwise, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Just to be clear, i really appreciate you trying to help me! How it should happen: Page loads, checkboxes A, B and C are unchecked, classes A, B en C are visible. Checkbox A got checked, classes B and C should disappear. Sorry, if i was not being clear. (and the document.ready thing has no influence it seems). @DavidThomas